# JQuery selector logical "and"

Tags: jquery

How can I access elements that have name `X` and type `hidden`?

Comment: Are you trying select an invisible element or a hidden input?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try this if you want `type=hidden`

```
$('input[name="X"][type="hidden"]')
```

If you want an element that is hidden via css then you should try

```
$('[name="X"]:hidden')
```

Comment: Remove "input" and that's exactly what he was asking for.  :)

Comment: You're missing the quotes on X and hidden.

Comment: @ StuperUser They are not required. But you can put them in if you have spaces.

Comment: @Mandoleen, did you mean type=hidden or hidden elements with style display none. Because those are different things and i can only think of input fields having type=hidden.

Comment: @Amir: I figure it's a good practice, even if you don't *have* to have them.  If you were to insert a value in there with PHP, for instance, you won't have it break mysteriously because there is an unexpected space.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar  : input with type "hidden"

Comment: @Amir : i use StuperUser 's method

Comment: Right but I am saying if it's an input field then don't remove the input. That is A LOT slower because it needs to look at every element instead of just input fields. You should always use most specific rule to speed up the selection!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('[type="hidden"][name="X"]');
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: Only input fields can have type=hidden so it would be best to put 'input[name="x"]' instead of just name because the it is much faster for the browser to look at only input fields.

Comment: +1, good point, but that would find type= text, button etc. too 'input[type="hidden"][name="x"]' would be stricter and meet OP requirements. It's also possible (but highly unlikely) that OP is selecting from invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="X"]:hidden').dosomething();
```

This will select an element with a `name="X"` attribute which is hidden.  You can learn lots more about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - there's plenty of useful help there.

Comment: No. Missing quote and the `:hidden` should be outside of the `[]`

Comment: This is actually wrong for two reasons. I think you mean [name="X"]:hidden. But this returns elements that are hidden not type=hidden.

Comment: Wow, that was a poor job of editing.  That's fixed.  I chose the :hidden selector because the question does not convince me that the OP wants hidden vs invisible.  I'm asking for clarification.