# Multiple condition selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, and I want to select the element with type = text and id of 'announcement_date'. How would I do this in jQuery? Note that both the elements have same id. This is in a legacy classic ASP page I am working with.

```
<input type="hidden" name="announcement_date" id="announcement_date" value="1111"></input>
<input type="text" name="announcement_date" id="announcement_date" value="323"></input>
<input type="text" name="eff_date" id="eff_date" value="123"></input>
<input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="123"></input>
```

I tried the selector below, but it fails to select the correct element.

```
$("#announcement_date type=text").addClass("error");
```

Comment: Don't use multiple identical ID values. It's invalid and has unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: I know IDs must be unique. But this is in legacy app, which is in classic ASP, which I do not want to change at this time.

Comment: Try this **([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rZRU/))**: `$(':text#announcement_date').addClass('error');`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IDs **have** to be unique.

(*if for some reason you cannot change the html*) you can select by name though as

```
$('input[name="announcement_date"][type="text"]');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it. You can also try it at http://jsfiddle.net/MBHCz/55/

Comment: @Sunil, it doesn't work because you have a space between the `] [` it shoud be `][`

Comment: SORRY. Your syntax works. Thanks. Please disregard above comment.

Comment: Sometimes, I think jQuery is ROCKET SCIENCE. Even a space makes a difference. LOL.

Comment: @Sunil, selectors in jQuery work just like in CSS.. And space is the delimiter between descendant selectors... So the space syntax in this code meant: find `[type="text"]` elements under a `input[name="announcement_date"]` element.. What we needed was for both attribute selectors to match the `input` element

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use id since having the same id on two elements is illegal in HTML.

(That is, fix your html to have unique ids then use id to select.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) idea.

So you could use..

```
$('input[type="text"][name="announcement_date"]')
```

Here is [a related SO question which is similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234462/jquery-selector-and)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="announcement_date"
class="announcement_date" value="1111" />

<input type="submit" name="announcement_date"
class="announcement_date" value="Submit" />
```

and then 
​

```
$(':text.announcement_date').addClass("error");
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MBHCz/63/)